# Directx11 vertexbuffer

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-12, vertex-buffer, directx-10

I'm trying to learn how to program a simple 2d game using directx 11 and I have a question regarding the vertex buffer, I created a 1.0f x 1.0f square to load a 512x512 pixel texture, to create a larger object and maintain the proportion I would have to create another vertexBuffer 2.0f x 2.0f with 1024x1024 texture?

To maintain the proportion, do I have to work with several vertexbuffers with different sizes? I use indexbuffer to draw.

Comment: `I would have to create another vertexBuffer 2.0f x 2.0f` No `with 1024x1024 texture?` and no. What object(s) are we talking about? Is one just an upscaled version of the other or are these two unrelated objects?

Comment: are unrelated objects

Comment: Meshes can be transformed using matrices, this includes scaling your 1x1 quad to 2x2. This is generally handled in the vertex shader. Which dimension of a texture you use depends on desired quality, whether you use linear filtering and how big this quad will actually be when rendered.

Comment: Another question, can I change the geometric shape from square to rectangle before calling the draw?

Comment: This can be done using matrices aswell.

Comment: do I do this by changing the scale matrix?

Comment: Dumb question of mine, I tested it here and that's it, thanks friend :)